# Когда System.getCurrentMillis() вернет значение больше предела long?

Tags: java

Мне вот интересно. Если `System.getCurrentMillis()` возвращается число секунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 года значением типа `long`, то когда это количество секунд перевалит за `Long.MAX_VALUE`? Вероятно, уже скоро! Какие меры будут предприняты? Придётся увеличивать предел `long`? Новый тип?

Comment: Кстати он показывает количество миллисекунд а не секунд.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это произойдет 292278994 году. Думаю до тех пор мы успеем что то придумать.

Значение лонга огромно. И тогда лонг просто уйдет в минус. Так что будет еще почти столько же времени.

Comment: Упс 0.o Где-то я неправильно посчитал :) Да, к тому уже времени уже насчёт этого не кому будет думать